# Firebase google-services.json

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I downloaded the google-service.json plugin from firebase and copied in my app folder within Android Studio. However, it differs from the standard look of this plugin.The marked line on the picture should actually contain a firebase url - at least, this url is given by default where its called: "https//projectman-4a752.firebaseio.com".
So is this actually and error or do newer version of that plugin no more contain this link?

I assume that this is the cause for the failure of firebase to recognize users who register within my app.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database can now exist in two locations, so it is not automatically created anymore when you create the project, but only once you explicitly go to the database panel in the Firebase console and select a location.

So to get the database URL in your `google-services.json`, create a database in the Firebase console, and then download the updated file.